# How can I calculate the length of intersection on a 2d line?

Tags: linear-algebra

The following diagram explains my question:

$\text{Line}A = [2,7]$

$\text{Line}B = [5,9]$

$X =$ The length of the intersection between LineA and LineB

[image: Intersection Line Length]

Thanks

Update: I ended up using this algorithm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marzullo%27s_algorithm

Comment: Note that the length is equal to $A\cap B$ if $A$ and $B$ are the sets of points in your line segments (the range of the empty set is $0$).

Comment: Can't you just see from the picture that the length is 2?

Answer (score 2):

It is $$\ell ([A_1,A_2],[B_1,B_2])=\begin{cases}
\min \{A_2,B_2\}-\max \{B_1,A_1\} & \text{If }\min \{A_2,B_2\}\geq\max \{B_1,A_1\} \\
0 & \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
In your example $7-5=2.$

Comment: Why +1? From the pic the length is 2.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Cause I have been in the discrete math section too long. I was thinking in cardinal. Thanks!